# "Wrap around" query possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not sure what is the correct term for this, but here is what I'm trying to do:

Suppose I have 10 items in my database (1, 2, 3 ... 10). When I am showing any single item (say item #3), I also want to load the next 5 items (so 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 in this case).

Now here is the tricky part: I always want to have 5 next items, so when I am at item #8 (for example), I want to "wrap around" and start from the beginning again, so the next 5 items are 9, 10, 1, 2, 3.

It is possible to do this in one query?

Comment: You should use two queries. If it actually turns out to be some kind of bottleneck (it won't) then you could spend mental effort to figure out a better way, but it really doesn't matter.